# Dolphin: unable to single click on files and directories to open it

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

Even if

1. I setted in system-settings->input devices->single click `
2. I tried `rm /home/pg/.config/dolphinrc /home/pg/.kde/.kde_save/share/config/dolphinrc /home/pg/.kde/share/config/dolphinrc`
3. I tried to remove my complete ~/.config directory and `restart sddm`
4. `sudo apt-get --reinstall install dolphin`

After upgrade to 15.10 it remains needing me to double click a file or directory to open it on dolphin... can anybody help me please? did the same update to my laptop and its working :-(

Comment: Checked right now for own Kubuntu - and I cant see this issue.

Comment: Still the case on my computer!

Answer (score 1):

It's related to migration between KDE4 and Plasma5 and bug is still not fixed in newest version from backports. You should try installing dolphin4 from repository as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Budznowski, is there a corresponding bug report? Is the bug still unsolved?

Comment: Do you have any idea on how i can make dolphin4 the default file manager? I set it up in Default Application as default file manager but when I use the file picker from Chrome (for example) it still open dolphin